# Bootloader priority issue

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, grub, bootloader

Good day to you all. I have a problem with the bootloader on my pc. I've followed a guide and i've partitioned my SSD so that now I have W8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is that when I switch my pc on Windows boots automatically, and to go on Ubuntu I have to shift-click on reboot to get an advanced reboot and i go on Ubuntu, which starts with GRUB2. My problem is that I can't boot directly into GRUB, and I tried going into BIOS, but i can't select which OS/partition to boot first!
(Secure/fast boot is disabled)

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I run msconfig, but Ubuntu doesn't show up. If I was to start EasyBCD, it lets me select Ubuntu as default OS, but when I reboot, it starts directly with Windows anyways. Even if it's still ticked as default...

Answer (score 0):

You obviously installed Windows and Ubuntu to MBR style disk.

Boot is controlled by Windows 8.1 boot manager.

As Windows 8/8.1 has the graphical boot menu enabled some preloading of Windows OS is taking place.

To get rid of this preloading you have to [set Windows boot menu to text style](http://www.boyans.net/BootMenuPolicy.html).

[image]

Comment: Hi snayob. I did this test too... this is my bcdedit: [IMG](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/2594/XCcyiD.png)... I don't know what happened, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Also, i've just checked, and I have a GPT disk

Comment: From your posted IMG of bcdedit output - You have to delete "displaybootmenu" element for {bootmgr}, or you can set same element to no.